# From binary image to shapefile

Tags: c++, opencv, shapefile

I'm developing a C++ application for image processing. I use OpenCV. I want to detect the coordinates of lines and polygons in my images to generate shape files in .shp format. My images are binary images that contain lines and polygons. My goal is to detect the lines and polygons and then generate a shape file that will contain them. I don't know how to do this so I'm turning to you. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I can retrieve the coordinates of my lines and polygons in my image. The problem is that I don't know how to convert them into geographical coordinates (lat/long).